# Установка GRUB в образ диска

Tags: linux, grub

Делаю образ диска так

```
fallocate -l 1G ./target.img
mkfs.ext4 -F ./target.img
```

Смещаю раздел, при разметке fstab раздел попадает в начало ФС.

```
fallocate --insert-range -o 0  -l 1048576 ./target.img

cat << EOF7 | fdisk ./target.img
o
n
p
1


a
w

EOF7
```

Ну а тут устанавливаю grub, без ошибок, диск загружается

```
mount -o loop,rw,offset=1048576 ./target.img ./target/
grub-install --recheck --boot-directory=./target/boot/ ./target.img
```

Но граб не находит загрузочный раздел, при загрузке ругается. Через kpartx тот же эффект.

Но если ставлю таким же способом на реальный диск - все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно записалось при подключении образа через losetup

```
losetup --partscan /dev/loop1 ./target.img
mount /dev/loop1p1 ./target
grub-install --recheck --boot-directory=./target/ /dev/loop1
losetup --detach /dev/loop1
```